# Figure Percentage by Group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, jupyter-notebook

My data looks like the below

```
| Position | Enrolled | Retained
| -------- | -------- |
| FT       | 1        |  1
| PT       | 1        |  0
| S        | 1        |  1
| FT       | 1        |  0
| S        | 1        |  0
| PT       | 1        |  1
```

I want to calculate the percent retained (Retained/Enrolled) by group.

I'd like my output to look like

```
FT .50
PT .50
S  .50
```

I tried the following:

```
df2.groupby(by=['Position']).(df2['Enrolled'].sum()/df2['Retained'].sum())
```

But that's not the correct syntax to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [`pd.DataFrame.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html), you can get pretty close (syntactically) to your proposed solution ;)

```
out = df2.groupby("Position").sum().eval("Retained / Enrolled")
```

out:

```
Position
FT    0.5
PT    0.5
S     0.5
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply`:

```py
calc_percent = lambda x: x["Retained"].sum() / x["Enrolled"].sum()
df2.groupby(by=['Position']).apply(calc_percent)
```

Out:

```
Position
FT    0.5
PT    0.5
S     0.5
dtype: float64
```